# Can't load QSQLCIPHER in Qt in Release mode

Tags: c++, qt

I've been compiled sqlcipher for Qt that used in my Qt App. In debug mode my sqlcipher plugins work fine but in release mode it said:

QSqlDatabase: QSQLCIPHER driver not loaded

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your plugin path (QApplication::libraryPaths()) & appropriate dll-s inside it. As I remember, there are always two copies of one sql plug-in - debug & non-debug.

Comment: Roman Kr: Unfortunately, i've input all dll inside it ant check it again. But not working....!